# Setting up proper testing for Django for TDD

Tags: django, testing, tdd, continuous-integration, bdd

I've been ignoring the need to test my project for far to long.

So I spent more than a day looking for ways to implement tests for my current apps and trying to get some TDD going for new apps.

I found a lot of "tutorials" with the steps: "1. Install this  2. Install that  3. Install thisnthat  4. Done!",
but noone seems to talk about how to structure your tests, both file and code wise.

And noone ever talks about how to set up a CI server, or just integrate the testing with the deployment of your project.
A lot of people mention fabric, virtualenv and nose - but noone describes how they work with them together as a whole.

What I keep finding is detailed information about how you set up a proper Rails environment with testing and CI etc...

Does anyone else feel that the Django community lacks in this area, or is it just me? :)

Oh, and does anyone else have any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately its hard topic. I have spend whole day creating working CI env. What I have accomplished is: tests, test-coverage, pylint, demo of application.

Comment: Its just you ;) See unittest2, mock, coverage, and Jenkins.

Comment: mkelley33: I didn't mean that there's a lack of tools, but the instructions on how to use them all together. Should I clarify my question?

Comment: agree with mkelley33, for instance: If you google "Hudson at Pycon" you'll find a really nice screencast about Hudson with some hints for the setup, it was enough for me at least :)

Comment: I agree that this topic is hard and fraught with peril. The Django testrunner coupled with 'unittest2' is not remotely sufficient. This is fine for writing a big ball of integration tests, but such tests are not good unit tests (they actually hit the database, which is slow, a primary failing for unit tests, so you don't have easy-to-write fast-running tests which provide good coverage.) Also, they don't exercise your whole app end-to-end (e.g. in a new process, or using Selenium.) hence they can never prove that your app actually works - a primary failing for acceptance tests.

Comment: There's a good talk about testing in Django by Carl Meyer (maintainer of Pip and Virtualenv, and no Django slouch either) from PyCon 2012: http://pyvideo.org/video/699/testing-and-django

Answer (score 9):

As I see it, there are several parts to the problem.

One thing you need are good unit tests. The primary characteristic of unit tests is that they are very fast, so that they can test the combinatorial possibilities of function inputs and branch coverage. To get their speed, and to maintain isolation between tests, even if they are running in parallel, unit tests should not touch the database or network or file system. Such tests are hard to write in Django projects, because the Django ORM makes it so convenient to scatter database access calls throughout your product code. Hence any tests of Django code will inevitably hit the database. Ideally, you should approach this by limiting the database access in your product code to a thin data access layer built on top of the django ORM, which exposes methods pertinent to your application. Another approach is for your tests to mock out the ORM calls. In the worst case, you will give up on this: Your unit tests become integration tests: They actually hit the database, cross multiple layers of your architecture, and take minutes to run, which discourages developers from running them frequently enough.

The implication of this is that writing integration tests is easy - the canonical style of Django tests covers this perfectly.

The final, and hardest part of the problem, is running your acceptance tests. The defining characteristic of acceptance tests is that they invoke your application end-to-end, as a user does in production, to prove that your application actually works. Canonical dhango tests using the django testrunner fall short of this. They do not issue actually HTTP requests (instead, they examine the url config to figure out what middleware and view would get called to handle a particular request, and then they call it, in process.) This means that such tests are not testing your webserver config, nor any javascript, or rendering in the browser, etc. To test this, you need something like selenium.

Additionally, we have many server-side processes, such as cron jobs, which use code from our Django project. Acceptance tests which involve these processes should invoke the jobs just like cron does, as a new process.

Both these scenarios have some problems. Firstly, you can't simply run such tests under the Django test runner. If you try to do so, then you will find that the test data you have written during the test setup (either using the django fixtures mechanism, or by simply calling "MyModel().save()" in a test) are in a transaction which your product code, running in a different process, is not party to. So your tests have to commit the changes they make before the product code can see them. This interferes with the clean-up between tests that Django's testrunner helpfully does, so you have to switch it into a different mode, which does explicit deletes rather than rolling back. Sadly, this is much slower. At last night's London Django user group, a couple of Django core developers assured me that this scenario also has other complications (which I confess I don't know what they are), which it is best to avoid by not running acceptance tests within the Django test runner at all, but creating them as a completely stand-alone set of tests.

If you do this, then your immediate problem is that you have lost the benefits the Django test runnner provides: Namely it creates a test database, and cleans it between each test. You will have to create some equivalent mechanism for yourself. You will need your product code to run against a test database if it is being invoked as part of a test. You need to be absolutely certain that if product code is run as part of a test, even on a production box, then it can NEVER accidentally touch the production database, so this mechanism has to be absolutely failsafe. Forgetting to set an environment variable in a test setup, for example, should not cause a blooper in this regard.

This is all before even considering the complications that arise from deployment, having parts of your project in different repos, dependent on each other, creating pip-installable packages, etc.

All in all, I'd love to hear from someone who feels they have found a good solution to this problem. It is far from a trivial issue as some commenters imply.

Comment: First of all, great reply!
We've ended up with mostly integration tests for the exact reasons stated above, and it takes minutes to run :)

I'd love to compare testing envs/ci envs with fellow djangonauts to see what kind of solutions there are and if someone has found a solution to the problems stated above.

Comment: Subsequent chats have lead me to the believe that one should not bother trying to clean the contents of the database between acceptance tests - they should be written in such a way that they do not care about the prior content of the tables. Eg, an acceptance test for 'adding a user' should not care if other users already exist. Presumably such a test should generate a new, unique username for each test run.

Comment: I'm belatedly realising that one way to address some of these issues is to write your application using the architecture pattern known as clean or hexagonal or ports'n'adaptors. If your core business logic contains no dependencies on external systems (including DB, network, filesystem) then you can unit test it thoroughly without mocking, and then need a much-reduced set of end-to-end acceptance tests to verify integration.

Answer (score 5):

Harry Percival is creating a Django / TDD / Selenium tutorial (and accompanying workshop, if you live in London.) His book reads like a hands-on tutorial, and goes into great detail on the subject:

https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/part1.harry.html

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, fine-grained unit tests for web apps are not worth it, the setup/teardown is too expensive and the tests are too fragile. The only exception is isolated components, especially those with clear inputs & outputs and complicated algorithms. Do unit-test those to the smallest details.

I had the best testing experience using a semi-functional testing tool called [testbrowser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.testbrowser), which simulates browser actions in Python. For integration with Django, install the [homophony](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/homophony) app (disclaimer: I am the author of the app).

Testbrowser may be a little too coarse for test-driven development, but it's the best testing tool of the ones I have used so far. Most importantly, it scales up fairly well, whereas unit tests and browser-based functional test tools tend to become very brittle as your app grows in size.

As for a CI tool, go with Buildbot or Jenkins.

Comment: If tests have expensive setup & teardown (eg the entire test takes longer than a millisecond), then they are not unit tests.

Comment: The most common mistake I see in testing is a failure to make sure each test is definitively either a unit test, or an end to end tests. Many projects end up with hybrid tests, halfway between the two. Such hybrid tests inherit none of the strengths of unit tests or end to end tests, and inherit all of the major weaknesses of unit tests and of end to end tests. This gives little payback for a large cost, leading to the erroneous conclusion that tests are just not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a combination of Django's [excellent extension](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/) of the python unittest framework for testing api's / models / helper functions, and selenium for in browser testing. Selenium has great instructions for how to set it up and write tests in python.